# Show that $(x-a,x-b)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

Knowing that $K$ is a field, $a,b \in K$ different from each other,show that $x-a,x-b$ co-primes.

We suppose that $\exists f(x) \in K(x)$ such that:

$f(x)|x-a$ and $f(x)|x-b$

Then $\deg f(x) \leq 1$

So, $\deg f(x)=0 \text{ or } 1$

If $\deg f(x)=1$:

$f(x)=x-c,c\in K$

$x-c|x-a ,  x-c|x-b \Rightarrow x-c| x-a-x+b \Rightarrow x-c|b-a$ contradiction,because that would mean $\deg(x-c) \leq deg(b-a) \Rightarrow 1 \leq 0$

If $\deg f(x)=0, f(x)=c,c \in K$

$c|x-a, c|x-b \Rightarrow c|b-a \Rightarrow c|(b-a)^{-1}(b-a) \Rightarrow c|1 \Rightarrow c=\pm 1$

So, $\gcd(x-a,x-b)=1$.

---

Do we suppose that $f(x)$ is just a common divisor of $x-a$ and $x-b$ or the greatest common divisor?? Also,at the case when $\deg f(x)=1$,why do we take $f(x)=x-c$ ??

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler: 
$$1=\frac{1}{b-a}((x-a)-(x-b))\in (x-a,x-b)$$

Comment: How does that show that x-a and x-b are co-prime?

Comment: @IlikeSerena It shows $1\in (x-a,x-b)$, thus $(x-a,x-b)$ is the whole ring, which is the usual definition of being coprime.

Comment: I see. It suspect it would help to explain what this ring and its membership means.

Comment: Another way of seeing it: for any Euclidean domain, if $ar + bs = t$, then $\gcd(r,s) \mid t$.  (This is one half of [Bézout's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).)  Since in this case $t=1$, the gcd must also be 1.